# CodeCollab GUI issues

Tags: clearcase, code-collaborator

I am trying to upload code to Code Collaborator via the GUI. When I enter the server url, username and password and select ClearCase as the SCM, I get the following error: Error: rational cm api for clearcase remote client not found. Has anyone encountered this before? What have you done to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

URL means that you are communicating with a CCRC server (a ClearCase Remote Client server) in order to review code stored in ClearCase.

The [CodeCollaborator (v7.0.7027) user guide](http://support.smartbear.com/resources/cc/usersguide.pdf) does mention:

> #### Support for ClearCase Remote Client (CCRC)
>
> CodeCollaborator integration with CCRC uses the Rational Change Management Server API.
>   When running the CodeCollaborator client installer, there is an edit field allowing you to
>   select the location of the Rational CM API jar files on your system. The required files are:
>
> - `remote_core.jar`
> - `stpcc.jar`
> - `stpcmmn.jar`
> - `stpwvcm.jar`
>
> These files are installed by the ClearCase Remote Client under the Rational Shared
>   Resource Directory.
>   The directory should look similar to one of the following:

```
C:\Program Files\IBM\IMShared\plugins\com.ibm.rational.teamapi_7.1.2.v201105310712
# or
/opt/eclipse/plugins/com.ibm.rational.teamapi_7.1.2.v201105310712
```

> Find the location of the files on your system and select or enter it during install so the CodeCollaborator installer can make them available to the CodeCollaborator client.
>   The installer will copy them to the following subdirectory under the CodeCollaborator client installation directory:

```
ui/plugins/com.smartbear.collaborator_7.0.xxxx/libs
```

> If using the RPM installer, you will have to manually copy these files to the correct
>   subdirectory.

So make sure you have those files present on the system, and copied on the CodeBear client installation directory.

Comment: This fixed the problem, although there is a typo on the 3rd jar file, it should be stpcmmn.jar. I know this is str8 from the smartbear website so it isn't your fault.

Comment: @Alessandro ok, I have fixed this typo.